# Salad canning in bags

Tags: canning

Where we live you can buy ready made salads like beetroot salad in vacuum sealed bags, so was wondering if you can use heavy duty vacuum bags to "can" things like jam, sauces and salads. You get those steam type bags that you can steam cook veggies in? Those type of bags ought to work? They are made to withstand heat?

Answer (score 0):

"Retort pouches" would be what you want for "can-less or jar-less canning" - Cooking bags are probably not really up to standard for long term storage.

I find the idea of canning salad odd, and likely to make many types of salad unpalatable, but I supposed if it's a "cooked salad" it might be fine.

Economically, unless you have a particular need that's served by flexible packaging, glass canning jars cost far less to use (and re-use, and re-use, and re-use.)